# How do i add a random number to each matrix element in matlab?

Tags: matlab, random

I have the following `matrix X` and `Column vector H`:

```
 X=[ 1 2 3; 2 3 4; 3 4 5];
 H=[1; 2 ;3];
 m=[X(:,1) H(:) X(:,2) H(:) X(:,3) H(:)];
```

How do i add a small random number to all elements of m while keeping every column H in the matrix m the same after adding the random number?

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear. Do you want to add a random number to every element, while keeping every column H *the same as it was before you added the random number* or do you want every column H *to be the same as every other column H* but different from before you added the random number. It would help if you gave some before/after example data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the random numbers separately, and then build your combined matrix.

```
Xnew = X + rand(size(X)); % replace 'rand' with the random numbers you want
Hnew = H + rand(size(H));
mnew = [Xnew(:,1) Hnew(:) Xnew(:,2) Hnew(:) Xnew(:,3) Hnew(:)];
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second line be `Hnew = H + rand(size(H));`?

Answer (score 0):

you can add the random to `X` instead of `m`

```
rX = X + rand(size(X)); % add uniformly distributed random numbers in [0,1] interval
m=[rX(:,1) H(:) rX(:,2) H(:) rX(:,3) H(:)];
```